# Show that the only Hausdorff topology on $X = \{a, b \}$ is the discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

The way I would of answered this is:
 
to be Hausdorff, all the points have to have an open neighbourhood which is not the whole space, as $X$ has only $2$ points, this would mean that both $a$ and $b$ are clopen hence its a discrete space?

I feel like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

There are few topologies on a set with two elements.

First there is the indiscrete topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$, the discrete topology $\mathcal P(X)$, and then you have the topologies where $\{a\}$ or $\{b\}$ are open but not both, i.e. $\{\emptyset,X,\{a\}\}$ and $\{\emptyset,X,\{b\}\}$, which are of course homeomorphic : this is the Sierpinski topology.

The indiscrete is clearly not Hausdorff, and the argument is the same to show that the Sierpinski topology is not Hausdorff, namely $a$ and $b$ don't have disjoint neighborhoods. So, the only remaining topology is the discrete one, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You said, "to be hausdorff, all the points have to have an open neighbourhood which is not the whole space." This isn't the definition of a Hausdorff space. A Hausdorff space $X$ is one in which each point needs to be "separable" from every other point in a specific way. That is, for each $x \neq y \in X$, there need to exist open sets $U$ and $W$ so that $x\in U$, $y\in W$, and $U \cap W = \varnothing$.

Think about how your hand gets forced if you include open sets to satisfy these conditions for $a$ and $b$.